# WYSIWYG slides, but with diff and source control

Tags: version-control, presentation

I'm looking for a WYSIWYG way to edit slides, such that I can later easily do version control and diff.

I could go the LaTeX/beamer way, but I don't want to have to actually write LaTeX code. Also, I want to be able to do pixel positioning. Markdown would also be acceptable, given the same caveats.

Ideal diff would be slide by slide, but line by line of code is also ok.

How can this be accomplished?